# Is it safe to shrink beginning of partition?

Tags: ext4, gparted

I have got paritions that look like this:
[image: Gparted screenshot]

And I would like to shrink /sda2 (home) for 2gb to right to make space to resize sda1 into 12GB. Is it safe to do it with gparted from live cd? Will I not loose any files?
File system is ext4

Answer (score 2):

`gparted` can do this easily.  BTW, in case you don't know, you have to reboot to a Live CD / USB because `gparted` can not safely move or resize filesystems that are mounted RW and in active use.  It can not move or resize the partition it is running from.   `http://gparted.org/` has downloadable ISO images for CDs and USB sticks.

anyway, here's the procedure:

1. Shrink `/dev/sda2` by 2G
2. move `/dev/sda2` to create 2GB of free space between `sda1` and `sda2`
3. resize `/dev/sda1` and give it the extra 2GB

Note that step 2 involves moving every byte of /dev/sda2.  This can be time-consuming.

BTW, do you really need 8GB of swap space?  e.g. you have 8GB RAM and are using suspend-to-disk.   If you're actually swapping that much, the correct solution is to add more RAM to the system.   If you're not doing suspend-to-disk, you might be better off doing this:

1. shrink /dev/sda3 by 4GB
2. optionally shrink `/dev/sda2` by 2GB or more
3. move `/dev/sda2` so that it is flush up against `/dev/sda3`
4. resize `/dev/sda1` to add 4 or 6 GB or more.

In the long term, though, your best option is to replace that 120GB `sda` (an SSD?) with a 256 or 512GB or larger SSD.  They've become a lot cheaper recently, and prices are likely to fall again dramatically in the near future.  If/when you do that, don't make the mistake of making a tiny rootfs again - if you can't allocate at least 20-50GB to root (depending on what software you need installed) then don't have a separate `/home` partition, just have one big `/` partition.

Comment: +1 @cas.
Always backup important data before moving, changing, resizing partitions. One might think this should go without saying, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the starting point of a partition is rather involved, and includes moving *everything* in the partition. So I wouldn't be surprised if gparted doesn't support that, but I have never used gparted. If it does support it, it's probably tested to the point that makes it safe.

Comment: ok, so any guess what to do if I get out of free space on / ?

Comment: @Mateusz first, next time (it's too late for this time) use LVM instead of raw partitions; it's much more easy to manage them and resize them in all sorts of fairly automated ways. Next, back everything up before you start. After you've done that, you may find it easiest to recreate the flesystem from a rescue/live image and restore the backup.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to shrink my partition only by using `gparted`. Instead, I had to first resize the filesystem with `resize2fs`:

```
resize2fs /dev/sdx# 50G
```

After that, I could shrink the partition with gparted without any problems or loss of data.
Note: resize a partition only, not your whole disk. So for example, instead of choosing sda, choose sda1.